# Taking a course after working hours

Tags: phrase-request

Well, 
Is there an English expression for courses that are after working hours?
Similarly to the difference between full time and part-time jobs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My dictionary has evening class/night class, but I think evening course would be possible, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use part-time here, if you like:

> I'm a full-time worker at Company A and a part-time student at School B.

This use is perfectly fine but it is unspecific about the time of day, so it leaves *when* you take the classes ambiguous.

If you want to specify classes taken after work hours (after 5 pm):

> [...] and I take evening/night classes at School B.

Some people take weekend classes (Saturday or Sunday), instead of evening classes:

> [...] and I take weekend courses at School B.

---

As a note, *classes* and *courses* are generally interchangeable here, as are *night* and *evening*.

Answer (score 1):

The following are a few phrases that can be used for courses after working hours:

Evening courses, night courses, after hours courses, etc.

A full-time job involves the full number of hours considered to be normal or standard, whereas a part-time job involves less than the normal or standard hours of working that people do.

Answer (score 1):

It is less common now, but it used to be standard to refer to any course whose classes were chiefly outside of business hours, whether that meant nights, evenings or weekends, as "night school".